# Typing capital ç on a French keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am using a French keyboard, but I'm not sure how to type a capital-ç on Windows XP SP2.

The key on the keyboard that has ç on it produces 9 when used with shift and ^ when used with <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>. Is the only option to type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> (on the numeric keypad)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it's the only option.

In a Linux box it is possible to directly type a capital ç. In Windows XP it is not.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#Missing_elements).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#Missing_elements links to the anchor of the section listing missing elements.

Comment: You're right. I'll update.

Comment: That's funny. The Canadian French (QWERTY) capital Ç, as well as all lower and upper-case accented letters, are easily accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Might be no help but...

I'm using a regular, US keyboard.  If I switch keyboards from "English (United States)" to "United States-International" then I can type `'C` (apostrophe followed by a capital C).

With the "United States-International" keyboard, some characters like apostrophe and double quote cause the next character to be modified with an acute accent or umlaut.

If you want, there are Windows XP keyboard editors that will let you remap keys.  You could take your current mapping and re-map a combination to Ç.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to make the lower case ç, select it and use shift+F3 in case you don't remember the numeric sequence

Answer (score 0):

Searching Google for *French keyboard* returned this [link](http://www3.uakron.edu/modlang/french/keyboard.html). I hope this works readily for you. If you still need another keyboard, I just cannot appreciate/evaluate the French keyboard, but I use the [Canadian Multilingual Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Canadian_Multilingual_Standard). You might compare with the *Canadian French (Quebec)* layout just above, in this last link.

Unfortunately I couldn't find the complete Canadian Multilingual Standard, and had to settle for a simplified one. This remains a mystery. I use AutoHotkey for other tweaks. As an endnote I also cannot understand why en.wikipedia.org says that the French-Canadian is more popular than the Multilingual: over the years I've never seen anyone not expecting É and Ç where i use them, nor met that famous keyboard... and since 2006 the Gouvernement du Québec has [adopted](http://www.msg.gouv.qc.ca/normalisation/standards/clavier/index.html) this standard@

[image]

Comment: Here is more or less full description of [French-Canadian keyboard layout](http://superuser.com/a/743921/220116). I like that French-Canadian layout :-).