# How to type French-specific characters «»° on a standard US keyboard on Windows using French-Canada layout

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

Having a Us keyboard on Windows using French-Canada layout, I can do a lot of the specific symbol/character and all of them are clearly explain in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/743920/how-to-type-french-specific-characters-on-a-standard-us-keyboard-on-windows-usin).

My question is only for the those characters.
 `« » °`

They are made using a key between the left shift and the z key. Since this key is not existant on US keyboard and I have try every key combination I could think off, I would need the help if someone knows the answer.

Comment: Take a look at charmap on Windows, it will help you for characters.  For °, press ALT and enter 0176 on the numerical keypad. « is ALT+0171, and » is ALT+0187.  Unfortunately, you need to use the keypad, the regular number keys don't work for this.

Comment: idk if this is also true for French Canadian PC keyboards [I'm used to Mac], but the 'missing' key left of z is actually moved to left of 1 for FrC. For US it's moved far right, between delete & Enter [Canadian seems to be a hybrid, ISO Enter key with ANSI 'missing left of z'.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### My question is only for the those characters « » °

- Use Alt+174 for `«`
- Use Alt+175 for `»`
- Use Alt+167 for `º`

The numbers should be typed on the numeric keypad (with NumLock enabled)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is in fact true, but it requires a numeric keypad. Since my new keyboard is a tenkeyless, I had no choice and switch to Canadian Multilingual.